# How to select relevant rows in Perl?

Tags: perl, conditional-statements

I need help altering this Perl code. I can get a list of all services on the host. But, I'm only interested in sending an email message for those services that are `Red` (stopped).  I'm not sure where I set that condition (within the foreach, perhaps)?

Output now:

```
Service: AeLookupSvc - Green - Auto
Service: Alerter - Red - Disabled
Service: ALG - Red - Manual
Service: AppMgmt - Green - Manual
```

Perl code:

```
my @servstat = ("Red","Green");
my $computer = "localhost"; 
my $winsvcs;

my $wmiObj = Win32::OLE->GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\$computer\\root\\CIMV2")
 or die "WMI connection failed.\n";

#get all services
my $servSet = $wmiObj->ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately | wbemFlagForwardOnly);  

foreach my $serv (in $servSet) { 
     my $sname = $serv->{name};
     my $sstate = $serv->{started};
     my $ssmode = $serv->{startmode};
    $winsvcs .= "Service: " . $sname . " - " . $servstat[$sstate] . " - " . $ssmode . "\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deal with the condition in the SQL query (only return the rows that are relevant - the Red ones).  This is probably the best way of dealing with it; it limits the data sent between DBMS and client (which may not matter much on a single machine, or on a LAN connection, but really matters on a WAN connection).

```
my $servSet = $wmiObj->ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Started = 0",
                             "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately | wbemFlagForwardOnly);
```

Alternatively, you can use a test in the `for` loop so that you add the relevant information to `$winsvcs` only if the `$sstate` is 0 (equivalent to Red).

```
foreach my $serv (in $servSet)
{ 
    next if $serv->{started};
    my $sname  = $serv->{name};
    my $sstate = $serv->{started};
    my $ssmode = $serv->{startmode};
    $winsvcs  .= "Service: $sname - $servstat[$sstate] - $ssmode\n";
}
```

Note that the `.` operator can be necessary (particularly if you need to embed the result of a function call), but wasn't really needed in the code you showed.  You could even do without the 3 loop variables, but then the line becomes rather long.

```
    $winsvcs  .= "Service: $serv->{name} - $servstat[$serv->{started}] - $serv->{startmode}\n";
```

Both methods will work.  I recommend modifying the SQL rather than the loop, but the choice is yours.

Comment: @cjd143SD: as you can see, I illustrated how I'd do it, but your technique would also work fine.

Comment: am getting error message `Not an ARRAY reference`, referring to `foreach my $serv (@{$servSet})`

Comment: @cjd143SD: I said I was making an assumption in the handling of `$servSet`; you've just proved that my assumption was wrong.  I see that the [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::OLE) package has a method `in(COLLECTION)`, so your original loop control code was OK; it was rather far from obvious that was the case.  That's the wonderful thing about Perl: TMTOWTDI (there's more than one way to do it).  Apologies for the misdirection.

Comment: Thank you. No apologies necessary. Its all part of learning perl for myself. I love this language. Its really my first programming lang. I see so many examples on how to do things, so I take what i can get :-)